# How to find DataValidation list for an Excel cell using EPPlus

Tags: excel, epplus

I have a workbook with a number of cells that have data validation specified as a dropdown list of allowed values.  Using EPPlus, I want to be able to get for each such cell, the list of allowed values.

So far I've got:

- `ExcelWorkSheet.DataValidations` gives me an `ExcelDataValidationCollection`, which is a collection of `IExcelDataValidation` items for the worksheet.
- Each `IExcelDataValidation` has an Address property of type `ExcelAddress` which presumably references all cells that have that validation rule.
- The step I'm stuck on is finding if a given cell is one of the cells included in the `ExcelAddress`

Any takers?

I'm currently using EPPlus 3.1.1.0, but can upgrade to a more recent version if necessary.

**UPDATE**

I didn't explain this clearly enough.  Here's my situation in more detail.

- Assume column C has some cells with list data validation.  Some cells allow, say, "A, B, C"; other cells allow "D, E, F" etc.  The range of cells for each data validation list is not contiguous, so, for example:

  - C2, C4, C7-C10, C20 may allow "A,B,C"
  - C3, C5-C6", C15 may allow "D,E,F"
- I'm trying to determine which cells allow "A,B,C" and which allow "D,E,F" etc.
- ExcelWorksheet.DataValidations contains ExcelDataValidationList items, one with values "A,B,C", one with values "D,E,F", etc.
- ExcelDataValidationList.Address for the list "A,B,C" contains an ExcelAddress whose Address property looks something like: "C4 C7:C10 C2 C20 ...".
- I want to determine if a given cell (say C6) is included in the range specified by this address "C4 C7:C10 C2 C20 ...".

Of course, I can String.Split on whitespace, and parse each item in the resulting list.  But I was hoping there would be some more direct way of doing this, e.g.

```
 ExcelAddress.Contains("C6")
```

or

```
 ExcelAddress.Contains(6, 2) // row 6 col 2 = C6
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost there, just check the `IExcelDataValidation`'s specific type. Tested with EPPlus 4.1.0.0:

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(path)))
{
    var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
    var validations = sheet.DataValidations;
    foreach (var validation in validations)
    {
        var list = validation as ExcelDataValidationList;
        if (list != null)
        {
            var range = sheet.Cells[list.Formula.ExcelFormula];
            var rowStart = range.Start.Row;
            var rowEnd = range.End.Row;
            // allowed values probably only in one column....
            var colStart = range.Start.Column;
            var colEnd = range.End.Column;
            for (int row = rowStart; row <= rowEnd; ++row)
            {
                for (int col = colStart; col <= colEnd; col++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(sheet.Cells[row, col].Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test worksheet:

[image]

Output:

```
one
two
three
```

Comment: sheet.Cells[list.Formula.ExcelFormula] are you sure that this is working?